# How to pass a command to a function in C

Tags: c, function

I'd like to pass a command to a function in C. The command is not fixed, it's just treated as a line of code in the function. As far as I know this cannot be done, but I'd like to check.

I'm playing with [Allegro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_(software_library)) and there are a lot of lines which I'd like to minimise. To illustrate the point I'd like to have a function where I can pass a primitive graphical command to, along with buffer, font and display and that command which I passed to the function is just treated as a line in the function.

E.g., void draw(buffer_1, font, disp, **al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!")**) =

```
al_set_target_bitmap(buffer_1);
al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello, World!");
al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(disp));
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(0, 0, 0));
al_draw_bitmap(buffer_1, 0, 0, 0);
al_flip_display();
```

This question isn't specific to Allegro; that's to illustrate the question.

I tried callbacks and couldn't get them to work. They are probably not fit for purpose.

I meant to illustrate that I was passing *al_draw_text* as the command into the function as the example. But I would like to be able to pass anything in, such as draw circle, draw line, etc. too.

Comment: It sounds like you just want another function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function pointer as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789807/function-pointer-as-an-argument)

Comment: This is probably operating system specific. I suppose you compile and run on Linux with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). You could embed in your C program some interpreter (like [Lua](https://lua.org/)....), you could write your own interpreter in C (study for inspiration some open source shell, perhaps [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)...). On POSIX systems be aware of plugins loadable with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and `dlsym`.

Comment: What is the "command" in your example and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the original question properly. I meant to illustrate that I was passing al_draw_text as the command into the function as the example. But I would like to be able to pass any command, such as draw circle, draw line etc. too

Comment: Hey 1toneboy, I think your question would be more clear if you gave two examples, to clarify which parts are in common, and which parts you wished were parameterized, and exactly you would like it to behave. Also, don't add your edits to an `edit:` message. Just keep one latest-and-greatest, most succinct version of your question. If people are interested in viewing the edit history, that's already a built-in feature of the site.

Comment: @tinman I don't think a mere function pointer wouldn't be enough here. If the colour, coords or text values are dynamic, then there would be no way to create a single static function that could be passed in. This basically requires a closure/lambda/whatever-we-call-it-these-days, which is something that would need to be hand-rolled in C.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481418/how-to-emulate-closures-in-c

Comment: @Alexander sorry I didn't see you'd replied here. I don't understand the significance of Closing threads on stackoverflow. I would say the only way I can make it more clear is to abandon this thread and refer to the thread "How to pass a block of code to a function in C?" which you linked to above. As I can't easily distinguish between the corrections in the OP here, and what was original, aside from making it bold, as I already did.

Comment: Hey again! "I don't understand the significance of Closing threads on stackoverflow." It's to enforce the site rules, which while not great (IMO), are generally geared towards making SO a high quality repository of Q&As, rather than a dumpster fire like Quora or Yahoo answers. "I would say the only way I can make it more clear" I gave you one idea for how to make it more clear: Give a few different examples, to clarify what part is in common, and what part is the "injected" part that varies.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but you can have a function that takes parameters of the appropriate type, and uses them to do things with.

I don't know the types that your example uses, but you could have something like:

```c
void draw(buffer_t *buffer, font_t *font, display_t *disp, int fg_r,
    int fg_g, int fg_b, int bg_r, int bg_g, int bg_b, const char *txt)
{
    al_set_target_bitmap(buffer);
    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(fg_r, fg_g, fg_b),
                 bg_r, bg_g, bg_b, text);
    al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(disp));
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(bg_r, bg_g, bg_b));
    al_draw_bitmap(buffer, 0, 0, 0);
    al_flip_display();
}
...
void foo(void)
{
    draw(buffer_1, font, disp, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example:

```
draw(buffer_1, font, disp, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!")
```

It seems you just want to pass the return value of the `al_map_rgb` to your `draw` function.  That being the case, since the return value of `al_map_rgb` has type `ALLEGRO_COLOR`, you should accept a parameter of that type.  Then inside your `draw` function, you would pass the value of this parameter as the second argument to the `al_draw_text` function.