# How to pass a block of code to a function in C?

Tags: c, function

I botched posting this question before as [How to pass a command to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117850/how-to-pass-a-command-to-a-function-in-c) but it was closed before I could correct it. I didn't write the original question properly. I meant to illustrate that I was passing al_draw_text as the command into the function as the example.

I'd like to pass a command to a function in C. The command is not fixed; it's just treated as a line of code in the function. As far as I know, this cannot be done, but I'd like to check. I'm playing with Allegro and there are a lot of lines which I'd like to minimise. To illustrate the point, I'd like to have a function where I can pass a primitive graphical command to a function, along with the buffer, font and display, and that command which I passed to the function is just treated as a line in the function.

E.g. `void draw(buffer_1, font, disp, al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!"))` =

```
    al_set_target_bitmap(buffer_1);
    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!"); //this line was passed in as function parameter
    al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(disp));
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(0, 0, 0));
    al_draw_bitmap(buffer_1, 0, 0, 0);
    al_flip_display();
```

This question isn't specific to Allegro; that's to illustrate the question. But I would like to be able to pass anything into a function, such as draw circle, draw line, etc.

I tried callbacks and couldn't get them to work. Probably not fit for purpose.

Comment: Hey there, please don't double-post questions. You can just edit your original question. While you're at it, you should respond to the people who generously offered their time to comment and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I did. It's still closed and so no one has replied. It was suggested in the closer message that one option was to re-post it.

Comment: I commented on your original question, but I'll elaborate here. I think your question is *still* unclear (and you can tell that others did too, given the variety of directions their comments/answers were going). Everyone is kind of just guessing your intent, and that's clearly not going to be very helpful to you. Further, you haven't engaged with any of the comments or answers. People took their time to answer you, but then you kinda just left and posted the same question again, equally unclear as the first time. If the answers are missing the mark, you should clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Why do you want  to pass those "commands" to a function? Why not just execute them? They are statements, so just write them down one by one like you do in your second snippet.

Comment: "I tried callbacks and couldn't get them to work." Callbacks are the answer here. Show what you tried and we can try to get it working.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The goal is to delay execution of the expression until a specified point in the `draw` function. In this case, the execution of `al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!")` should be delayed until after the `al_set_target_bitmap(buffer_1);`.

Comment: How would you pass music to a musician?  Probably by codifying it and writing in the form of sheet music and giving it to a musician that can interpret the sheet music to give the performance.  Similarly, how would you "pass a command to a function"?  Probably by codifying it and passing the coded version of the command to some function that can interpret it.  So you'll need a data structure that represents both a command and all its arguments, and then call a general function that can execute any concrete command given your codification of it.  Such a mechanism is called an _interpreter_.

Comment: Do you want to reorder execution of the passed commands inside `draw`? Based on what?

Comment: @Wyck, the implication of your suggestion is that there are distinct functions created for each possible application of calling draw(...) e.g. draw_line(...), draw_triangle(....). Rather than one universal draw(...) function? Thanks

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. I want to be able to call draw(...) where I pass what I want to draw (which is an allegro command) as the parameter (and pass which buffer to draw it on), which has some fixed inclusion lines of code in it which don't change, like al_clear_to_color() and al_flip_display(); Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want to create your own function called `draw`? Do you already have a function called `draw` defined by whatever framework you are using that you want to call? What is an allegro command, in terms of the C language?

Comment: Think about how `printf()` is able to translate _n_ parameters into a consecutive collection of ASCII characters. It handles `char`, `int`, `double`, `string`... Perhaps it invokes its helper functions, in sequence and with sub-parameters, and they each perform their specialised task in the right order; an order dictated by the caller of `printf()`... Perhaps you want to investigate variadic functions and 'parsing' each parameter from a "command sequence specifier". Have fun!

Comment: How would `draw_line` differ from `draw_triangle`? Do you know what are function pointers?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I beg your pardon. Allegro is a graphics library, which can be used in the C language. I want to create a function called draw, which can take any command and insert that command as a line within the function draw. Thanks

Comment: The only "command" that exists in the C language is a string you pass to the `system` function, see [the standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf, search for the word "command"). Nevermind, I understand what you want to do. The only way you can do that is as described in the answer by KamilCuk. I understand that you want a lot more, but you can't have it, because C does not support it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, thanks. At least I know it can't be done and will cease trying. I'll have to write individual tailored function variants for each primitive graphic, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> where I pass what I want to draw (which is an allegro command) as the parameter (and pass which buffer to draw it on), which has some fixed inclusion lines of code in it which don't change

Pass a function pointer. Call that function.

```
void draw_hello_world(font_t font) {
    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!");
}

void draw(buffer_t buffer_1, font_t font, disp_t disp, void (*fn)(font_t font)) {
    al_set_target_bitmap(buffer_1);
    fn(font);
    al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(disp));
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(0, 0, 0));
    al_draw_bitmap(buffer_1, 0, 0, 0);
    al_flip_display();
}

int main() {
   draw(buffer1, font, disp, draw_hello_world);
}
```

I see "font" is specific to drawing hello world. What you typically do is to pass a "cookie" to the function pointer to pass relevant context needed for the function. See for example POSIX `fopencookie` or `qsort_r` functions. Here's an example with a struct for the parameter: (struct is not needed, you could pass `&font` as the cookie, put just to showcase an exampe with struct):

```
struct draw_hello_world_params_s {
    font_t font;
};

void draw_hello_world(void *cookie) {
    const struct draw_hello_world_params_s *p = cookie;
    al_draw_text(p->font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!");
}

void draw(buffer_t buffer_1, disp_t disp, void (*fn)(void *cookie), void *cookie) {
    al_set_target_bitmap(buffer_1);
    fn(font);
    al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(disp));
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(0, 0, 0));
    al_draw_bitmap(buffer_1, 0, 0, 0);
    al_flip_display();
}

int main() {
   const struct draw_hello_world_params_s draw_hello_world_params = { font = some_font; };
   draw(buffer1, disp, draw_hello_world, &draw_hello_world_params);
}
```

C programming language does *not* have lambdas. If you are up to using  specific compiler language extensions (which means your code may *not* compile with other compilers), you can check [gcc nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

And finally, there are also macros:

```
#define draw(buffer_1, font, disp, ...) do { \
    al_set_target_bitmap(buffer_1); \
    do{ __VA_ARGS__; }while(0); \
    al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(disp)); \
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(0, 0, 0)); \
    al_draw_bitmap(buffer_1, 0, 0, 0); \
    al_flip_display(); \
} while(0);

int main() {
    draw(buffer_1, font, disp, al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!"));
}
```

Macros are hard to debug, hard to manage and are a simple text replacement.

Comment: Clearly I've done a terrible job explaining what I'm trying to achieve sorry everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is a lambda function, but possibly, so might not be possible. What I'm trying to do is have basically write a function where one parameter of the function is inserted within, as a line of code.

Comment: I have seen an edit. I do not understand. Yes, if you want to write code, you have to write code, if you want to pass parameters to a function, you have to write the function and parameters. May be C programming language is not for you, and you want to write concise nice looking code - consider python, c++ or rust. In C, you would create a function, and pass parameters, as in my answer.